# github | force pushed --orphan branch ~•~ lost all data/website ~•~ recoverable?

Tags: git, github, git-push, recover

> preface ~ i'm still a very  green programmer + i attempted to resolve the issue below w/ the step-by-step assistance of claude.ai

## initial issue

`git push` repeatedly errored: `GH001: Large files detected.`

## resolution [planned]

remove tracking of large file in my local repo

## resolution [executed]

1. use git-filter-repo to target large file + remove all instances of it in my local commits

- the file in the referenced path has already been deleted but the tracking of it persisted after running the following command several times:
  `git filter-repo --force --path public/posts/ver0_38/_hu930a8f636c08bb7a0f4cd2a5ff120114_26684426_d46344f3bad075e4893718ebcea2de5c.gif`

2. after suggesting i clone the last good remote repo, i preferred to resolve the issue in a more targeted approach by fixing the error at its source ~ so, ***claude*** then suggested we `create an --orphan branch` then `force push it up to my remote repo`

- at this point, i was a bit frustrated in attempting to resolve this + various other errors in the past 3 days that prevented me from pushing/updating my *hugo site* ~ so, despite ***claude*** giving me clear instructions of *copying* the files + folders from my *hugo directory* to a temp folder as a backup then *copying* them back after creating the `--orphan branch`, i only *moved* the files + folders out then right back in the *hugo dir* without ever having backed them up ~
- once i `force pushed` this `--orphan branch`, all the files within my *hugo website* were gone + only the empty folders remained ~ ***claude*** did explicitly warn me that this was a "nuclear reset", but being in the rushed state of mind i was in to resolve this persistent issue, i read right past the critical details, following the directions blindly without realizing how destructive of a process this was ~

## my plea for help

while i backed up my local `hugo directory` a few days prior to this `nuclear incident`, the commit history for this repo was very important to me as it marked the start of my second attempt at coding/programming + i would have loved to have the breadcrumbs of my journey available for later review + reflection ~

so, is it at all possible to undo this deletion/resetting of my `hugo directory` so that i can retrieve/recover both my deleted branch, and therein all my data, as well as my original repo w/ all of its commits?

i would truly, truly appreciate any assistance  kreme

> attached are claude's instructions

> also, after this, not having yet realized the full extent of what happened, i wanted to revert my local branch to being called main instead of new-main ~ so, w/ chatgpt being unaware of the context, it instructed me to create a new main branch then we deleted the new-main branch, this may have been the stuff to delete my data but i'm not sure

[instructions by claude.ai](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtJT2.png)

Comment: Does the reflog contain the branch you were working on? Do you recognize any of the branch names and/or commit messages in the reflog?

Comment: when i ran `git reflog`, the following was printed:

`5de2ec0 (HEAD -> main) HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from new-main to main
7f0bb36 (origin/main, new-main) HEAD@{1}: commit (initial): Fresh start`

so there really isn't any history other than the commit message that was entered when creating the --orphan branch that overrode my main branch w/ all my data + past commits

Comment: What about `git log --reflog` (or, for a GUI view, `gitk --reflog`)? Does it show any commits not associated with a branch/tag?

Comment: @LokiRagnarok | nope, just the two commits mentioned earlier of creating the initial commit of the new branch ["fresh start"] + changing branches

Comment: What about `git reflog --all`?

Comment: What about `git fsck --unreachable | grep commit` (slow, give it time)?